# How to add items list to spesific existing list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list, let's say that is `[data: [{'city': 'jakarta'}, {'city': 'Manchester'}]`. I want to add new items for every items exist like `[data: [{'city': 'jakarta', 'wide':189.000}, {'city': 'Manchester', 'wide': 200.122}]`. How it works ?

here my codes

```
temp_data = []
sql = "some queries"
result_sql = db.find_all(sql)
for num, city in enumerate(result_sql):
   temp_data.append(city)
return jsonify({'data':temp_data})
```

Comment: `[data: ...` is not valid syntax. Please post the actual code you're using.

Comment: the question have been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your `wide` values stored in a list in the same order of your `data`:

```py
data = [{'city': 'jakarta'}, {'city': 'manchester'}]
wide = [189.000, 200.122]

for e, w in zip(data, wide):
    e['wide'] = w

print(data)
```

Comment: i haven't `wide`, i don't know to add my list existing